# WPF ItemsControl DataTrigger EnterActions Animation not starting

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard, datatrigger

I have a problem with an animation within a template of an `ItemsControl` that is part of the template of another `ItemsControl`. I want a path, that is representing an Icon, to change its color and constantly rotate when a certain condition becomes true.

The `DataTrigger` generally works, causing the `Fill` of the Path changing from Gray to LightGreen when the `producing` Property changes to `true`. However, the animation does not start. When I let the animation start with the `Loaded` Event (as you can see in the commented section), it starts properly. So I know that the animation, as well as the `DataTrigger`, is configured correctly.
When I put the **same Path** (just copy and paste) in the outside `ItemsControl` and change the `DataTrigger` to a Property of the corresponding `DataType`, the animation also works as expected. So there seems to be a problem with the nested ItemsControls, but I have no idea what it might be.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Computers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:ClientComputerWrapper}">
        <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
          <StackPanel>

            <!-- Some Content -->

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PlcReaderStatuses}">
              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type resources:PlcReaderStatusResource}">
                  <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">

                    <!-- Some Content -->

                    <Path DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Data="{StaticResource GearIconGeometry}" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                      <Path.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="gearPathTransform"/>
                      </Path.RenderTransform>
                      <Path.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Path">
                          <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
                          <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsProducing}" Value="True">
                              <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightGreen"/>
                              <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="rotateStoryBoard">
                                  <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="360" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                  </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                              </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                              <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="rotateStoryBoard"/>
                              </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                              <!--<BeginStoryboard x:Name="rotateStoryBoard">
                                <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="360" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                              </BeginStoryboard>-->
                            </EventTrigger>
                          </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                      </Path.Style>
                    </Path>
                  </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a solution. After trying to replace the `DoubleAnimation` with a `ColorAnimation`, using `(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)` as `TargetProperty`, I received an error that the path is not pointing to a `DependencyProperty`. This was only solved when I defined the `SolidColorBrush` explicitly in a `Setter` which led my to try the same with the `RenderTransform` of the `Path`:

```
<Path.Style>
  <Style TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="RotateTransform">
      <Setter.Value>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="gearPathTransform"/>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!-- ... -->

  </Style>
```

Afterwards the animation works as expected. I still don't know why this is only necessary in the inner `ItemsControl` and it is also nasty that there is no error as is for the `ColorAnimation`, but at least it is working now.